# Cannot find module 'http' or its corresponding type declarations while I try include ytdl-core

Tags: angular, ytdl

I download ytdl-core for angular project running `npm install ytdl-core --save` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core). For use this module I do:

```
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core';

ytdl(url);
```

When I launch angular app it show the next message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/miniget/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'D:\workspaces\customer\node_modules\miniget\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/miniget/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'D:\workspaces\customer\node_modules\miniget\dist'

    ERROR in node_modules/ytdl-core/typings/index.d.ts:2:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http' or its corresponding type declarations.
2   import { ClientRequest } from 'http';
                                  ~~~~~~
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by dependencies of  node modules that are not available in the browser.
Add these to your package.json file.

```
"browser": {
  "http": false,
  "https": false,
  "net": false,
  "path": false,
  "stream": false,
  "tls": false
}
```

Delete your node_modules folder and run these commands

```
npm install
npm install stream
npm install --save-dev @types/node
npm install ytdl-core --save
```

Go to your `node_modules/ytdl-core/typings` folder and remove these line from `index.d.ts`

```
import { ClientRequest } from 'http'; // Delete this
```

[image]